# Difficulty in getting smooth scroll function built using Jquery to function correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having difficulty in getting my Jquery smooth scroll function to work I have no idea why it is not working please see code below

```
  //Jquery Smooth Scroll
$('.navbar a').on('click', function(e) {
if (this.hash !== '') {
    e.preventDefault();

    const hash = this.hash;

    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        },
        800
      );
    }
});
```

however when I click on on my navbar i get this error message:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
  at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:9)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is in hash for example?

Comment: Anchor links for menu navigation for example <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

Comment: So its href not hash. Try to make breakpoint in dev tools and call $(hash). I bet there will be error. I think to get href it will be $(this).attr('href')

Comment: Thank you for your response I have now found the issue

Comment: You welcome :) :)